# Java - Out of Bounds Exception Database

Tags: java, sql, debugging

I am practicing Java before the semester starts, and I trying to create code that will read in a specified CSV file, and create a database with it. But I am getting an error that says

"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    
at LoadData.main(LoadKids.java:52)"

My code is listed below.

 The error is on this line "Rating = fields[3].trim();"

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class LoadData {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection c = null;
    Statement s = null;
    Scanner fromFile = null;
    String sql1 = null, sql2 = null;
    String line = null, ID = null, Console = null, Title = null, Rating = null, Multiplayer = null;
    String[ ] fields;

    try {
        // Define Connection and Statement objects.
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:games.db");
        s = c.createStatement();

        // Instantiate scanner to read from file.
        fromFile = new Scanner(new File ("FileName.csv"));

        // Create the table.
        sql1 = "create table if not exists " +
            "games(gameid integer, " +
            "ID varchar(2), " +
            "Console varchar(15), " +
            "Title varchar(20), " +
            "Rating varchar(2), " +
            "Multiplayer varchar(3));";
        System.out.println("sql1: " + sql1);
        s.executeUpdate(sql1);

        // Read and throw away header line.
        fromFile.nextLine( );

        // Populate the table.
        for (int id = 1001; fromFile.hasNextLine( ); id++) {
            line = fromFile.nextLine( );
            fields = line.split(" ");
            ID = fields[0].trim();
            Console = fields[1].trim();
            Title = fields[2].trim();
            Rating = fields[3].trim();
            Multiplayer = fields[4].trim();
            sql2 = String.format(
                "insert into games (gameid, ID, Console, Title, Rating, Multiplayer) " +
                "values (%d, '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s');", 
                id, ID, Console, Title, Rating, Multiplayer);
            System.out.println(sql2);
            s.executeUpdate(sql2);
        }
        c.close( );
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File queries.sql not found.");
        System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + 
            ": " + e.getMessage() );
    }
    catch(SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("SQLException.");
        System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + 
            ": " + e.getMessage() );
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e ) {
        System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + 
            ": " + e.getMessage() );
    }
    finally {
        fromFile.close( );
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Are you reading CSV file? You are splitting line by spaces and looks like line is split by spaces into only 3 pieces.

Comment: Upon each iteration, test that the fields array contains enough elements to fulfill the desired variables: if (fields.length <= 0) { continue; }  if (fields.length >= 1) { ID = fields[0].trim(); } if (fields.length >= 2) { Console = fields[1].trim(); } ets, etc.

Comment: Change the following line 
 'fields = line.split(" ");'  
into  'fields = line.split(",");'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please post the data in your csv file.
Normally CSV files are separated by commas, hence the name comma separated values.  However, you code is using a space to separate the values.

```
fields = line.split(" ");
```

If your CSV data is really separated by commas, change that line to

```
fields = line.split(",");
```

If your CSV data is separated by spaces, verify there are at least 5 items separated by spaces on every line in the file.

Comment: Thank you so much, I don't know how I overlooked that. It is separated by commas, but I did think I messed up the CSV file so I looked it over twice.